# FileUploaded function return thumbnail after upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I used this api called [`plupload`](http://plupload.com) and i want to return thumbnail images after files uploaded. Every time it upload image it will return it's thumbnail and be put in a div or after ajax called it will return all the images uploaded. this is my code:

HTML:

```
 <div class="well" id="prevCap">
```

javascript: PLUPLOAD

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) {
    self._handleFileStatus(file);
    self._trigger('uploaded', null, { up: up, file: file } );

    if (uploader.files.length == (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
        var prev = '<img class="img-thumbnail" src="./assets/images/upload_tmp/'+ file.name +'">';
      $("#prevCap").append(prev);
    }
});
```

THis is working but it only returns one image which is the last image uploaded. So i'm thinking of how can i return filenames or the image file from ajax. or there is other way to return all image uploaded. I'm newbie in javasript and plupload.

Comment: check this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2563-showing-plupload-image-previews-using-base64-encoded-data-urls.htm

Comment: this blog is good and it gives me hint from what i want to do. But it only shows previews before they were uploaded. what i did was after uploading it will show another thumbnail inside my div.